# How to order a Queryset containing foreign key objects to a model by related model's primary_key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to know of a way to achieve this for a very simple case.
I have Room object with Facilities as it's foreign key. Consider four rooms(R1 to R4), with each room connected to only one facility object.

Suppose related mapping for Rooms is R1->F4, R2->F1, R3->F2, R4->F3 
(R1 is first room, F1 is facility connected to first room and so on)
(All F1-F4 can even be same facility object)

querying database on filtering Room object returns < R1, R2, R3, R4 >
(All rooms returned ordered by room_id)

So, I want to know how to query database by filtering Facilities object to return < F4, F1, F2, F3 >
If all rooms were connected to a single facility F1, I want final result to be
 < F1, F1, F1, F1>

my models.py file

```
class Room(Base):
    facilities = models.ForeignKey(Facilities, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room_type = models.ForeignKey(RoomTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    offer = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

# Facilities object that describes what all facilities are present in a room
class Facilities(Base):
    storage = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    locker = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    tv = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    bathroom = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    iron_table = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    balcony = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    garden = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    wifi = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    refrigerator = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ac = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cctv = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I want to select all facilities (that are connected to at least one room) and order them by room_id. I want to have same number of Facilities returned as there are rooms.
Database is MySql, and I am using Django-ORM to handle all queries.

Stated in other words, I want to perform SQL Join operation b/w Room and Facilities, common column is Facility id in both tables that connect a room and facility. And then I want to order the results of facilities, with lower Room id's to be displayed first.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please improve your question by providing example tables and the expected output, as well as specifying what query language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add related_name to facilities field in room

```
class Room(Base):
    facilities = models.ForeignKey(Facilities, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rooms")
```

And you can get all de facilities ordered by room with:

```
Facilities.objects.order_by("rooms")
```

I'm not sure what is the sintax if related_name is not set.